# Set id and name in typo3 powermail form

Tags: typo3, powermail

I am kinda new to typo3 and after 3h of looking for an answer I resign and hope someone of you can help me. So what I am trying to achieve is a hidden field in a powermail form with a certain id and name. I can add a hidden field in the backend but there is no option to set an id nor name. I guess it is somehow possible to do this with some typoscript but I couldn't find a way in the docs. The closest thing I read is this https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/AddNewFieldProperties/Index.html but this let me create a whole new template for a field as I understood. This is way too much as I only need to set the id and name for one field only.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/MDGU0Q3Ie value for name same for ID with prefix "powermail_field_"

Comment: Hey thanks. But this changes it to tx_powermail_pi1[field][MYNAME]. But I need it to be just MYNAME. And the same for the ID.

Comment: I am just wondering why do you need it, since if it will not have tx_powermail:_pi1 prefix, powermail will not read its value and send it in an email.

Comment: This is for google offline conversions. Google fills in the gclid in a given input field which has to have a specific name and id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a field with a complete own name for some reasons, you could add a field of type HTML and add your input field as you want (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForEditors/AddANewForm/FieldHtml/Index.html). Of course powermail ignores this field in the createAction().

BTW: You wrote something about google. Are you sure google can handle fields in POST-requests? If not, you have to add the value as GET value in powermail. That must be done in the Form HTML-Partial.